# Using java invoke Postgresql's procedure

Tags: java, postgresql, call, procedure

From the document of postgresql i found that :

`con.setAutoCommit(false);`

### Procedure call.

```
CallableStatement proc = con.prepareCall("{ ? = call doquery ( ? ) }");
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.Other);
proc.setInt(2, -1);
proc.execute();
ResultSet results = (ResultSet) proc.getObject(1);
```

refer [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/jdbc-callproc.html)

While, I tried to create a procedure just like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PSSQLPRC(pA IN VARCHAR,pB IN NUMERIC,PC OUT NUMERIC)
RETURNS NUMERIC
AS $$<br> begin

... ... 
end;
$$ Language PLPGSQL;
```

Using java to call the postgresql procedure likes below

```
CallableStatement proc = con.prepareCall("{ ? = call PSSQLPRC(?,?,?) }");
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NUMERIC);
proc.setString(2,"abc");
proc.setInt(3,10);
proc.registerOutParameter(4, Types.NUMERIC);
proc.execute();
```

when the CallableStatement's object to exectue , error will occur. What can i do resolve the error? Are statements above correct?

Comment: When i debug it, the sql statement change as **select * from PSSQLPRC ('null','abc', '10', 'null') as result** in the statement, and it cannot find the PSSQLPRC with four parameters... Thanks a lot!

Comment: the sql statement change as **select * from PSSQLPRC ('null','abc', '10', 'null') as result** in the statement(CallableStatement's object)...

Comment: If you want to pass `null` don't enclose it in single quotes. `'null'` is a character literal, `null` is the null value.

Comment: Hi,my concern is it cannot find the procedure with four parameters,i defined the procedure with three parameters in PSSQL... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need 2 return values from your stored procedure?
If not, try changing the function to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PSSQLPRC(pA IN VARCHAR,pB IN NUMERIC)
RETURNS NUMERIC
```

And the Java code:

```
CallableStatement proc = con.prepareCall("{ ? = call PSSQLPRC(?,?) }");
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NUMERIC);
proc.setString(2,"abc");
proc.setInt(3,10);
proc.execute();
```

Comment: Hi,Perter Thank you very much for your help... I'd like to ask few  more questions:1.Is it correct while with two return values using java to invoke PSSQL PROEC?2.If i really need two return values how can i run it use CALL...   Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi,Perter It seems that you are right! The function PSSQLPRC of postgresql with out type parameter will auto change and omit the out type parameter when we success create it ....